# Can't run my node.js Project after cloning it from my repo

Tags: node.js, npm

After clone my project , I try to install different packages and runs it but unfortunately while installing dependencies, facing these errors. And I can't be able to install any dependency or anything else. Anyone know what's the issue?? Thanks in Advance

```
 npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ncr-api-serverless\node_modules\keytar
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:416:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
```

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Node did you check this box? I had a similar issue that was resolved by checking the box in the picture below. It seemed to fix the Python path etc.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I actually did it. But same error